# Running sequence alignment using biopython

Tags: bioinformatics, biopython

I am interested in running mafft from biopython. It works fine (code below).

```
from Bio.Align.Applications import MafftCommandline
mafft_cline=MafftCommandline(input="file.fasta")
print(mafft_cline) 
stdout, stderr = mafft_cline()
output.write(stdout)
```

But I wanted to add in the additional parameter of adjusting the direction of the sequences based on the first sequence (the reference one). In the documentation, I found this written down, but I am not sure how to incorporate it into my code above:

## Mafft V6 beta function

```
_Switch(["--adjustdirection", "adjustdirection"], 
"Adjust direction according to the first sequence. " 
"Default off."), 
# Adjust direction according to the first sequence 
# for highly diverged data; very slow 
# Mafft V6 beta function 
_Switch(["--adjustdirectionaccurately", "adjustdirectionaccurately"], 
"Adjust direction according to the first sequence," 
"for highly diverged data; very slow" 
"Default off."),
```

I tried a few things like
    mafft_cline=MafftCommandline(input="file.fasta", --adjustdirection)
but it comes back with an error.

Thanks!

Comment: Can you show the exact error?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You do this by setting the `adjustdirection` property of `mafft_cline`. By default, it is `False`.

```
>> from Bio.Align.Applications import MafftCommandline
>> mafft_cline = MafftCommandline(input="file.fasta")
>> print(mafft_cline.adjustdirection)
False
>> mafft_cline.adjustdirection = True
```

We now see that the `--adjustdirection` switch is added to the commandline.

```
>> print(mafft_cline)
mafft --adjustdirection file.fasta
```